# reading documents from different apps on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I want to ask that can I access the books which are saved in **iBooks or in any other application** on iOS devices. **Can I  import those books in my iOS apps?**

I tried to use **UIDocumentInteractionController** but it didn't work. So, I'm looking for any other alternative solution which I can apply in my app.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: iOS is sandboxed. You can open documents from other apps when those support sharing/export of the documents. Otherwise this is not possible.

Comment: thanks dasdom for your comment. Can you please tell me that how can I find out that is there any app on ios device that supports sharing of document within apps?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to access the documents data of some other app (unless Jailbroken), this would be breach of security/privacy, any app who would try to do so by any means will be reject in App Store review.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to some files outside of your app container with [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html) with iOS 8. But you'll only get access files the user chooses and that other apps have made available at the right place. This is not the case for books.

Comment: actually i want to access different document that are stored on iPhone device. There is no centralized storage that we can access. So, I wanted to know that can I access pdf or doc files that are saved in iBooks..??